# How to authenticate Prestashop API REST Client

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, prestashop, refit

I created an interface to call the Prestashop API using Refit, for a Bot App I'm developing.
In order to call the API you need to authenticate with a Prestashop API Key, which I have. To query using the browser I only need to call an url with this format:

```cs
$"https://{ApiKey}@{mypage}.com/api"
```

And it authenticates using the Api Key specified before the `@` sign. To define the Refit `HttpClient` i use this code in the Startup.cs:

```
// This is the ApiUrl from the appsettings.json file
var apiUrl = Configuration.GetSection("PrestashopSettings").GetSection("ApiUrl").Value;

// We add the Api and specify the de/serialization will be XML
services.AddRefitClient<IPrestashopApi>(
    new RefitSettings
    {
        ContentSerializer = new XmlContentSerializer()
    })
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(apiUrl));
```

Then I inject the API to one of my classes and call one of its functions. The URL seems correct, if i paste the complete URL (the base + the [Get] url) to a browser it returns an XML correctly. But when I do it from the App it returns an exception:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter:Error: Exception caught : Refit.ApiException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Refit\RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 274
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

What is the correct way of Authenticating using Refit's HttpClient? Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**

So I tried this:

```
public class HttpAuthentication : HttpClientHandler
{
    private readonly string Token;
    public HttpAuthentication(string token)
    {
        Token = token ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(token));
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = Token;
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

And this code in my `Startup.cs`:

```cs
var apiKey = Configuration.GetSection("PrestashopSettings").GetSection("ApiKey").Value;
var storeUrl = Configuration.GetSection("PrestashopSettings").GetSection("StoreUrl").Value;

// We add the Api and specify the de/serialization will be XML, and we specify the Authentication Client.
services.AddRefitClient<IPrestashopApi>(
    new RefitSettings
    {
        ContentSerializer = new XmlContentSerializer()
    })
    .ConfigureHttpClient((c) => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(storeUrl))
    .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder((c) => new HttpAuthentication(apiKey));
```

And I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out at the end.
First of all I want to point out there's two solutions around this.

**First Solution**

You can actually authenticate using your API Key as a Request parameter, its key is `ws_key`, so you can send a call like this:

```
"https://api.yourapiaddress.com/yourentity?ws_key={API KEY HERE}"
```

**Second solution**

This is the one I opted for, just adding a Header Parameter. Found out Prestashop API 1.7 uses Basic Authorization with the API Key as username and a blank password so I built the header like this in `Startup.cs`:

```
// Encode your Api Key
String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(apiKey));

// Add the API to DI in Dialog classes
services.AddRefitClient<IPrestashopApi>(
    new RefitSettings
    {
        ContentSerializer = new XmlContentSerializer()
    })
    .ConfigureHttpClient((c) => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(storeUrl))
    .ConfigureHttpClient((c) => c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded));
```

I used the ConfigureHttpClient function of Retrofit but you could actually achieve the same by creating your own HttpClient object and configuring the DefaultRequestHeaders like this.

Answer (score 0):

create class like this :

```
 public class AuthenticatedHttp : HttpClientHandler
    {
        private readonly string Token;
        public AuthenticatedHttp(string token)
        {
            if (token == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(token));
            }
            this.Token = token;
        }
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // See if the request has an authorize header
            var token = this.Token;
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

and send Token To this class:

```
var token = await GetAccessToken();
            var RestReq = RestService.For<IPerson>(new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttp(token)) { BaseAddress = new Uri(Url) });
```

Comment: I guess where the `token` should be the Api Key, and the header value you assigned to "Bearer" is an identification that can be any value? Or this needs to be something in particular? Then I need to create a [Header()] attribute in the api class or something?

Comment: First step you send rest request to auth api and get the token .
then use above code.

Comment: Can you please answer where in the code should I use my Api Key? I have to use it in order to access the Api and I can't see it anywhere explained.

Comment: you should set Api key to header request . like this

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token")

but because you can use refit above code solve your broblem

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer I updated the post after trying your solution, still having the same problem.